# Which argument in Nano saves the file automatically?

Tags: nano

I'm trying to saves the file automatically in Nano but didn't succeed. what is the option to do this?

Comment: No such argument mentioned in the man page.

Comment: then have similar argument in VIM????

Comment: I don't think there is, but I don't use it or have it installed. Unix console text editors are used to edit system configuration files and automatic saving may lead to dire consequences or even a dead system altogether. You could use LibreOffice instead.

Comment: Use GNU Emacs: No data loss in 32 years!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [nano manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) for version 6.2

```
-t, --saveonexit
              Save  a changed buffer without prompting (when exiting with ^X).
              (The old form of the long option, --tempfile, is deprecated.)
```

You can also add `set tempfile` to `~/.nanorc`.

But, like the comment by @Artem mentions, be careful when editing config files with auto save.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/922613/how-to-exit-nano-and-save-to-current-file-automatically